# Need to calculate table TPS (Transactions Per Second)

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the records from a table in such a way that I need to TPS(Transactions per second).
Means how many Transactions were made in one second, DateTime column exists in table.

Comment: Add the `CREATE TABLE` DDL, sample data (`INSERT` statements), expected results, and the query you tried to your question.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman Let me do it.